# How do I update vue data based on axios response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

How can I put data from axios to vue js data: `value: [parseInt(this.maintemp1),parseInt( this.maintemp2)], <--------Here is my problem`

```
    export default {
  data: () => ({
    maincity: "",
    maintemp1: "",
    maintemp2: "",
    maindate1: "",
    showLabels: true,
    lineWidth: 2,
    labelSize: 7,
    radius: 10,
    padding: 8,
    lineCap: "round",
    gradient: gradients[5],
    value: [parseInt(this.maintemp1),parseInt( this.maintemp2)], <--------Here is my problem
    gradientDirection: "top",
    gradients,
    fill: true,
    type: "trend",
    autoLineWidth: false
  }),
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=khiva&units=metric&appid=myapi"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.wholeResponse = response.data.Search;
        this.maincity = response.data.city.name;
        this.maindate1 = response.data.list[1].dt_txt;
        this.maintemp1 = response.data.list[1].main.temp;
        this.maintemp2 = response.data.list[9].main.temp;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: since it's dependent on other data properties, make `value` a `computed` property. `value: [parseInt(this.maintemp1),parseInt( this.maintemp2)],` doesn't lock a function, but a value in data()

Comment: added example of code change in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `data` option values are evaluated before even `mounted` method is called. So, when `value` is set initially then `maintemp1` & `maintemp2` are empty strings. Also, `value` is not a computed property here, thus it does not track the changes for `maintemp1` & `maintemp2` either. One option is to set the `value` inside the axios `.then()` method.

So, first set `value` to an empty array in `data` like:

```
data: () => ({
  ...
  value: [],
    ..
}),
```

and then inside `mounted` update like:

```
axios
  .get(
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=khiva&units=metric&appid=myapi"
  )
  .then(response => {
    this.wholeResponse = response.data.Search;
    this.maincity = response.data.city.name;
    this.maindate1 = response.data.list[1].dt_txt;
    this.maintemp1 = response.data.list[1].main.temp;
    this.maintemp2 = response.data.list[9].main.temp;

    this.value = [parseInt(this.maintemp1), parseInt( this.maintemp2)];
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` is a computed property. `data` contains list of static things which can change over the time in your component, but they are still just the values. If your property is dynamically dependent on other properties, you should have it in `computed` like below:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    maincity: "",
    maintemp1: "",
    maintemp2: "",
    maindate1: "",
    showLabels: true,
    lineWidth: 2,
    labelSize: 7,
    radius: 10,
    padding: 8,
    lineCap: "round",
    gradient: gradients[5],
    gradientDirection: "top",
    gradients,
    fill: true,
    type: "trend",
    autoLineWidth: false
  }),
  computed: {
     value() {
       return [parseInt(this.maintemp1),parseInt( this.maintemp2)],
     }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=khiva&units=metric&appid=myapi"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.wholeResponse = response.data.Search;
        this.maincity = response.data.city.name;
        this.maindate1 = response.data.list[1].dt_txt;
        this.maintemp1 = response.data.list[1].main.temp;
        this.maintemp2 = response.data.list[9].main.temp;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
```